# Editing and updating table data using a form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, localhost, edit

I am new to Laravel and am trying to edit the data in phpmyadmin using a form but i am getting errors and have not made any progress

heres my form code

```
@extends('layouts.admin_template')

@section('content')
<div class="container mb-5">
    <h1 class="text-center text-dark">Edit rewards program</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/reward_edit">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="my-5">
            <label for="reward_program_name" class="form-label text-dark fw-bold">Rewards program name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reward_program_name" value="{{ $rewardsprogram->reward_program_name }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="my-5">
            <label for="reward_program_ID" class="form-label text-dark fw-bold">Rewards program ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reward_program_ID" value="{{ $rewardsprogram->reward_program_ID }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="my-5">
            <label for="description" class="form-label text-dark fw-bold">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ $rewardsprogram->description }}" required>
        </div>
        <div class="d-grid col-3 mx-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

heres the controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\rewardsprogram;
use App\Http\Requests\StorerewardsprogramRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdaterewardsprogramRequest;

class RewardsprogramController extends Controller
{

public function edit($id)
    {
        $rewardsprogram = rewardsprogram::findOrFail($id);
        return view('reward_edit', compact('rewardsprogram'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(UpdaterewardsprogramRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $rewardsprogram = rewardsprogram::findOrFail($id);
        $rewardsprogram->reward_program_name = $request->input('reward_program_name');
        $rewardsprogram->reward_program_ID = $request->input('reward_program_ID');
        $rewardsprogram->description = $request->input('description');
        $rewardsprogram->save();

        return redirect('/reward_edit')->with('status', 'success');
    }
```

heres the route code

```
Route::get('/reward_edit/{id}/edit', [rewardsprogramController::class, 'edit'])->name('reward_edit.edit');
Route::put('/reward_edit/{id}', [rewardsprogramController::class, 'update'])->name('reward_edit.update');
```

I am getting errors such as PUT and GET method is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

In the form you are calling the action: `action="/reward_edit"` ,  without passing the `id` as you defined at your route: `reward_edit/{id}`.
So it probably hits another route that accepts a post type method. That's why it is throwing the error,  that route does not support GET and PUT methods